# Is there any other way except POJO to send response in form of JSON from server side to angular?

Tags: angularjs, dropwizard

Hi i am at my elementary stage in learning dropwizard with angularjs, my problem is that when i send response from my resource at server side as POJO, it gets parsed into JSON, but if i send any String, angular throws me error, please help me out how can i send my custom response to angular.

Comment: Please post the code that throws the error + errors.

Comment: Is it not possible to call json encode on the server side? Actually I don't quite understand how you get to send a POJO without converting it to JSON first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to set the response type to plain text. This could be done like this:

```
@Path("/example")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class EndPoint{

    @GET
    public Response saySomething() {
        return Response.ok("plain text response").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }

}
```

once you have that covered you can use angular's $http service to read the plain text response:

```
$http({method: "GET", url: "/example"})
  .success(function(data){ 
      alert(data) // alert: plain text response
  }
);
```